# Objective-C SpriteKit Create dotted line to certain points

Tags: objective-c, position, sprite-kit, touch, dotted-line

I have a certain point at the bottom of the screen . . . when I touch the screen somewhere, I'd like a dotted line to appear between the point, and the point my finger is at. The length and rotation of the line will change based on where my finger is, or moves to.

I'm assuming I'd make the dotted line with a repetition of a small line image, but I guess that's why I need your help!

Answer (score 2):

Note that all this can be organized better, and I personally don't like SKShapeNode in any shape :) or form, but this is the one way to do it:

```
#import "GameScene.h"



@implementation GameScene{
    SKShapeNode *line;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    line = [SKShapeNode node];
    [self addChild:line];
    [line setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];

}

-(void)drawLine:(CGPoint)endingPoint{

    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, endingPoint.x,endingPoint.y);

    CGFloat pattern[2];
    pattern[0] = 20.0;
    pattern[1] = 20.0;
    CGPathRef dashed =
    CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath(pathToDraw,NULL,0,pattern,2);

    line.path = dashed;

    CGPathRelease(dashed);
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        [self drawLine:location];

    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        [self drawLine:location];

    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    line.path = nil;

}
```

The result is:

[image: drawing dashed image]

Also I don't know how much performant this is, but you can test it, tweak it and improve it. Or even use SKSpriteNode like you said. Happy coding!

**EDIT**:

I just noticed that you said dotted (not dashed) :)

You have to change pattern to something like:

```
 pattern[0] = 3.0;
 pattern[1] = 3.0;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Whirlwind! If that works like the gif shows, it's exactly what I need! I'll get back with you to let you know for sure.

Comment: Again, this is just what I want . . . But do you have any idea how to continue that dotted (or dashed) line to follow its path past your finger, and bounce off the walls? Making sort of a reflection? I can understand if that's pretty difficult. I don't even NECESSARILLY need some code, just an idea of how that would work :)

Comment: I don't have any idea at the moment, sorry. If I came up with something useful I will update my answer. Maybe you should ask another question because probably answer for that would be more complex than this one. There is one good article about trigonometry and stuff like calculating angles, bouncing of the walls and similar (there is part 1 and 2): http://www.raywenderlich.com/90520/trigonometry-games-sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-part-1 Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again. I'll follow your advice . . .

EDIT:
I did end up using the code you gave me, and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @ChristianKreiter note that SKShapeNode is not performant solution in many cases, so make sure you do performance testing always. Also if this answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted. And welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: You caught me! I'm a new member, lol

What do I say? "Accepted?"

Accepted!

Comment: Great Answer! I was looking for this exactly!