# SKShapeNode to follow touch

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch, skshapenode

I'm trying to find out how to create an SKShapeNode line upon touch and have the end point follow the touch.  I've figured out how to create the line over and over but not to actually dynamically change its end point based on the current touch position.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks.
Here is my current code:

```
func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    if captain.contains(pos){
        selectedUnit = "p1"
    }
}

func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    if selectedUnit == "p1" {
        let line = SKShapeNode()

        startPoint = CGPoint(x:captain.position.x,y:captain.position.y)
        endPoint = pos

        pathToDraw.move(to: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y))
        //            pathToDraw.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: endPoint.x, y: endPoint.y))
        pathToDraw.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pos.x, y: pos.y))

        line.zPosition = 100
        line.path = pathToDraw
        line.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        line.lineWidth = 5
        self.addChild(line)
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359136/3402095) or?

Comment: How do I mark this as a duplicate question?