# Use spritekit to draw bounce auxiliary line

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

use swift & spritekit,I have a polygon with a point of origin. 
With the finger move, I want to launch a dotted line from the origin to the direction of the finger clicks. 
When the dotted line hits the polygon, it can bounce,just like the bubble dragon game. Can you give some advice?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "with the fingers move" ? How many fingers are describing (1, 2, multiple)? Where were the fingers placed and where do they move to?

Comment: one finger...My mistake

Comment: Perhaps you should break your question up into multiple questions, search SO to solve each question, then come back and show what you have attempted.  Your questions are 1)How to draw a dotted line, 2) How to change angle the dotted line so that it always follows the touch 3) How to make a line bounce.  I can assure you, all three of these questions have been asked on SO.

Comment: Here is the answer for 1) and 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359136